# משיח צדקך vs. דוד עבדך

Tags: yom-kippur, king-david, selichot

After viduy during the Yamim Noraim selichot, we have several paragraphs quoting pesukim about teshuva.  The second one starts with

> משיח צדקך אמר לפניך

On Yom Kippur, this is changed to

> ודוד עבדך אמר לפניך

and quotes the same pasuk.

Why do we refer to David in different terms?

Comment: In nussach sfard וכיסא דוד עבדך לתוכה תבין.        על ידי דוד משיח צדקך ימלוך ה' אלוקייך ציון לדור ודור הללוך

Comment: @kouty I understand they both refer to David Hamelech.  I'm asking why we call him one thing during the weekday selichot and something else on Yom Kippur.

Comment: I'm skeptical this isn't just you using two different editions on the two days that derive from parallel different Nuscot.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "Sefer Kushyos" from a contemporary of the students of the MaHaRaM of Rotenburg who writes on page 159 מכאן סמך "אין שלטון ביום המות" (קהלת ח ח), כי זה
יום הדין.

Which would mean, since it's a day of judgement we don't want to "flower up" our prayers with titles.